# Error on login connection with ZF2

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Currently I am creating an authentication module.
I work with Zend Framework 2.5.1, coupled Doctrine 2.

When I try to connect, once posted my form, I have the following error: Missing parameter "id"

Here is my login action (**in AuthController**):

```
public function loginAction()
{
    /** @var ServiceLocator $serviceLocator */
    $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();

    /** @var Authenticate $authentication */
    $authentication = $serviceLocator->get('service.user.auth');

    if ($authentication->hasIdentity()) {
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/user',
        [
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action'     => 'profile',
        ], [], true);
    }

    if (($prg = $this->postRedirectGet()) instanceof Response) {
        return $prg;
    }

    /** @var Login $form */
    $form = $authentication->getForm();

    if ($prg !== false) {

        $form->setData($prg);

        if ($authentication->authenticate()) {

            $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/user',
            [
                'controller' => 'user',
                'action'     => 'profile',
            ], [], true);
        }

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $messages = $authentication->getMessages();
        }
    }

    return compact('form', 'messages');
}
```

And the routing that matches my authentication:

```
return
[
    'router' =>
    [
        'routes' =>
        [
            'home' =>
            [
                'child_routes' =>
                [
                    'user' =>
                    [
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' =>
                        [
                            'route' => 'user[/:action][/:id]',
                            'defaults' =>
                            [
                                'controller' => 'user/user',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ],
                            'constraints' =>
                            [
                                'action' => 'index|register|update|profile',
                                'id'     => '[0-9]+'
                            ],
                        ],
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                        'child_routes' =>
                        [
                            'auth-login' =>
                            [
                                'type' => 'Literal',
                                'options' =>
                                [
                                    'route' => '/login',
                                    'defaults' =>
                                    [
                                        'controller' => 'user/auth',
                                        'action' => 'login'
                                    ],
                                    'constraints' =>
                                    [
                                        'action' => 'login|logout',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

A little help would be welcome, I'm not sure why this error ..

Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the config, try `'id' => '[0-9]*'` with `*` instead of `+`, since the `+` means that it should have at least one digit.

Also, did you have a look on https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/ which provides such functionality for you to use. and you can use it with Doctrine, in addition to many RBAC and Access List authorizations modules...

Comment: OK for ZfcUser, I know this module.

But I prefer doing this by myself. This is an exercice, for improve my knowledge about ZF2.

About the id, if I made the modifications you tell me and going to www.blabla.com/user/login, I have an error: page not found..

Comment: This is another thing, this error means the first error is solved...  so now you have to follow the new issue, maybe the controller or the action name is not spelled right, try to change the controller name and/or action name to debug such issue. Maybe you need to put the action names in the constraints inside [ and ]... try also to remove the constraint to see what heppens

Answer (score 0):

I try everything you said, this is the same error. Debug the routing is not realy easy in ZF2.

For information, I have 2 modules: Application, and User.
So it's the routing for Application module:

```
<?php
return
[
    'router' =>
    [
        'routes' =>
        [
            'home' =>
            [
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' =>
                [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' =>
                    [
                        'controller' => 'application.index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

Comment: WHen you open the website (/), do you see the content of the indexcontroller/indexaction?

Comment: /index, /index/user/profile, /index/user/register are OK.
But for child_routes /index/user/login, I have the error